# repeating nodes using for loop but when concating xml string then concat only last iteration of for loop?

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

I stuck with a problem that I am using FOR loop for generating repeating nodes.
   Now when I concat the generated node in the main node then I got only last iteration of that FOR loop.
  can anybody suggest me a way to handle this error....

```
FOR i IN 1..pl_phone_tab.Count
 LOOP
 SELECT xmlelement("Phone"
                     ,xmlelement("PHONETYPE",xmlattributes('01' AS "dmnADRP_PHONETYPE"),pl_phone_tab(i).p_phtype_tab)
                     ,xmlelement("PHONENUM",pl_phone_tab(i).p_phnum_tab)
                     ,xmlelement("PRIMARY_CONTACT",pl_phone_tab(i).p_prcon_tab)
                  )
 INTO p_phone_xml
 FROM dual;
 END LOOP;


SELECT xmlelement("PhoneInfo"
                       ,xmlconcat(p_phone_xml))
 INTO p_phone_info_xml
 FROM dual;
```

here I am getting only one node but there has to be two nodes for PHONE node

Answer (score 0):

Each loop iteration overwrites previous value of `p_phone_xml`, so at the end you have only the last table element in XML.

Use `xmlconcat` inside a loop to append each iteration result to `p_phone_xml`.

```
FOR i IN 1 .. pl_phone_tab.Count
LOOP
  SELECT xmlconcat(p_phone_xml
                  ,xmlelement("Phone"
                              ,xmlelement("PHONETYPE"
                                         ,xmlattributes('01' AS
                                                       "dmnADRP_PHONETYPE")
                                         ,pl_phone_tab(i).p_phtype_tab)
                              ,xmlelement("PHONENUM"
                                         ,pl_phone_tab(i).p_phnum_tab)
                              ,xmlelement("PRIMARY_CONTACT"
                                         ,pl_phone_tab(i).p_prcon_tab)))
    INTO p_phone_xml
    FROM dual;
END LOOP;

p_phone_info_xml := p_phone_info_xml.appendchildxml('/somepath/PhoneInfo'
                                                   ,p_phone_xml);
```

Comment: but then it'll repeat the whole xml (or node) this is a small piece of a node I have to concat these nodes in a node and then this node to main XML....so please can you show me way to achieve this task I am stuck here from 2 days

Comment: Do you mean that you already have some XML in `p_phone_info_xml` and you want to append `p_phone_xml`?

Comment: yes you can take it that way also..but the logic i'll explain you what I am implementing here is I am generating a big complex XML here and in that xml I have different nodes so for each node I am creating a different procedure and later I concatenate these nodes in the main XML to make my code modular.now here in this node PhoneInfo have a small node phone which is repetitive in nature because there can a mobile phone or a basic landline phone. So this PhoneInfo node will get concatenate with contactInfo node and contactInfo will get concat in the main node.problem is with repetitive node.

Comment: I want to append p_phone_info_xml with p_phone_xml which is of repetitive in nature. then this p_phone_info_xml will get to concatenate with contactInfo node and then contactInfo node will get add to main xml.So if I solve this repetitive node issue then i'll generate the whole XML...And foobarbaz I am generating this XML with IN parameter of pl/sql in which some them are of nested table type so can you also show me a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Check the solution now and remember to replace `'/somepath/PhoneInfo'` with a correct XPath.